# How to fix the wrong minification on constants declaration with Uglify v.^3.17.4?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

The code I have:

```
export function SomeComponent({captions}: {captions?: string[]}) {
  const {firstConst, secondConst, thirdConst} = someVariable

  const text = captions && captions[firstConst]
  const max = secondConst - thirdConst
  const digits = Math.max(2, String(max + 1).length)
  //...more codes
}
```

However, when I try to minify, the code came out as:

```
function SomeComponent({
    captions: e
}) {
    var {
        index: r,
        total: o,
        visible: a
    } = t, e = e && e[r], o = o - a, a = Math.max(2, String(1 + o).length);
    // ...more code
}
```

As you can see, I'll get error on `e = e && e[r]`, `o = o - a` and `a = Math.max(2, String(1 + o).length)`. The error message is:

`Identifier 'e' has already been declared (14:48)`

and so on...

The current uglify setting is just on default (with no custom settings)

```
UglifyJS.minify(code)
```